# Castle Windsor: Re-registration of a Named component maintains previous Lifestyle

Tags: castle-windsor

The below Unit Test fails, and I am looking for a valid reason for it doing so.

```
interface IFoo { }
class Foo : IFoo { }
class Foo2 : IFoo { }

[TestMethod]
public void LifestyleTest4()
{
    WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().Named("foo").LifeStyle.Singleton);

    IHandler h = container.Kernel.GetHandler("foo");
    Assert.IsTrue(h.ComponentModel.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Singleton);

    bool removed = container.Kernel.RemoveComponent("foo");
    Assert.IsTrue(removed);

    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo2>().Named("foo").LifeStyle.Transient);

    h = container.Kernel.GetHandler("foo");
    //Assert will fail as LifestyleType == Singleton
    Assert.IsTrue(h.ComponentModel.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Transient, "Expected Transient Lifestyle");
}
```

Even though the component was removed from the container, it appears that a reference to the LifeStyle is maintained by name.

I am using the 2.0 release.

Comment: Please report it to the user list or to donjon (http://www.castleproject.org/issuetracker.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krzysztof is right, this looks like a bug.

The reason is that the component configuration, which contains the lifestyle, is **not** removed by RemoveComponent, so the first lifestyle configuration will be always used.

Workaround: add this line after calling RemoveComponent():

```
container.Kernel.ConfigurationStore.GetComponentConfiguration("foo").Attributes.Remove("lifestyle");
```

Please report it to the issue tracker (include your testcase) and link back here, this could serve as a starting point to fix the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, can confirm it works. Will report as a bug as advised.

Comment: Bug report: http://support.castleproject.org/projects/IOC/issues/view/IOC-ISSUE-160

Logged in using OpenID, and it seems to have logged as reported by another account (jsimons)...but none the less it is the report that stemmed from this post.